# How to join mulitple SQL query set?

Tags: sql-server

I want to join different SQL result sets into one result. all the sql query should be Left join

Example:

SQL 1:

```
Select t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num, count(t1.Catg_code) as m_cnt
From model t1, car t2
Where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  and t1.model = 'CD' 
Group by t1.Model_id,t1.Model_num
```

SQL 2:

```
Select t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num, count(t1.Catg_code)as e_cnt
From model t1, car t2
Where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  and t1.model = 'EM' 
Group by t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num
```

SQL 3:

```
Select t1.Model_id, t1.prod_cd, t3.startdate, t3.enddate 
From prod t1, master t3
Where t1.model_id = t3.model_id
```

How to make all above SQL result sets into one result?

This is the desired result:

```
Model_id  Model_num   m_cnt   e_cnt   startdate    enddate
-------------------------------------------------------------
011       100001        3       4     04/04/2020   04/04/2020
022       200001        1       2     05/05/2019   05/06/2019
```

Comment: [union all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results as there is some confusion over what exactly you want. (as text *not* images).

Comment: please find my sample data above I have updated

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query will handle your issue and also you should change your join style

```
Select t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num,NULL, count(t1.Catg_code) 
From model t1, car t2
Where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  and t1.model = 'CD' 
Group by t1.Model_id,t1.Model_num

UNION ALL 


Select t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num,NULL, count(t1.Catg_code) ,NULL,NULL
From model t1, car t2
Where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  and t1.model = 'EM' 
Group by t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num

UNION ALL 

Select t1.Model_id, NULL,t1.prod_cd,NULL, t3.startdate, t3.enddate 
From prod t1, master t3
Where t1.model_id = t3.model_id
```

Comment: Union ALL merge the data in one column .. I want merge column like left join. for example If I used union all it will merger all count catg_code into one column. Its different column .I want add as different coulm

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much of the table structure it's hard to tell what actually you are trying to do. However, in first 2 queries you are joining the `model` table with `car` table without selecting any field of `car` table which maybe means that you only want to select the lines from `model` where a corresponding `car` exists, if that's not the case then I don't see any reason why you are joining these tables.

But anyways here's an example how you can achieve it by doing a sub-query.

```
declare @model table (
            Model varchar(100)
            , Model_id varchar(100), Model_num varchar(100)
            , Catg_code varchar(100)
            );

declare @car table(Model_id varchar(100));

declare @prod table(Model_id varchar(100), Prod_cd varchar(100))

declare @master table(Model_id varchar(100), StartDate date, EndDate date);


insert into @master(Model_id, StartDate, EndDate)
    values
        ('011', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-04')
        , ('022', '2019-05-05', '2019-06-05');

insert into @prod(Model_id, Prod_cd)
    values
        ('011', 'prod-cd-01')
        , ('022', 'prod-cd-02');

insert into @model(Model, Model_id, Model_num, Catg_code)
        values
            ('CD', '011', '100001', 'catg-code-01')
            , ('EM', '022', '200001', 'catg-code-02');

insert into @car(Model_id)
    values ('011'), ('022'), ('011'), ('011');


select  p.Model_id, p.Prod_cd
        , (
            select  count(1)
            from    @model as m
                    inner join @car as c on m.Model_id = c.Model_id
            where   m.Model = 'CD'
                    and m.Model_id = p.Model_id
        ) as m_cnt
        , (
            select  count(1)
            from    @model as m
                    inner join @car as c on m.Model_id = c.Model_id
            where   m.Model = 'EM'
                    and m.Model_id = p.Model_id
        ) as e_cnt
        , m.StartDate, m.EndDate
from    @prod as p
        inner join @master as m on p.Model_id = m.Model_id
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried this but am receiving error like "116: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Answer (score 0):

This might work but its not the most elegant way to do this

```
SELECT tbl_1.Model_id, tbl_1.Model_num, m_cnt, e_cnt, startdate, enddate
FROM

(Select t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num, count(t1.Catg_code) as m_cnt
From model t1, car t2
Where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  and t1.model = 'CD' 
Group by t1.Model_id,t1.Model_num) tbl_1

LEFT JOIN

(Select t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num, count(t1.Catg_code)as e_cnt
From model t1, car t2
Where t1.model_id = t2.model_id
  and t1.model = 'EM' 
Group by t1.Model_id, t1.Model_num ) tbl_2 ON tbl_1.Model_id = tbl_2.Model_id

LEFT JOIN

(Select t1.Model_id, t1.prod_cd, t3.startdate, t3.enddate 
From prod t1, master t3
Where t1.model_id = t3.model_id  ) tbl_3 ON tbl_1.Model_id = tbl_3.Model_id
```

Comment: Thank you :) .I tried this I am getting error like "156:incorrect syntax error SELECT'

Comment: @Div Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected the query.. You can just copy & paste

Answer (score 0):

With very little detail all I can do is make a guess:

```
SELECT
    prod.Model_id
  , COALESECE(model.Model_num, prod.prod_cd) prod_cd
  , model.count_cat_num
  , mst.startdate
  , mst.enddate
FROM prod
INNER JOIN master mst ON prod.model_id = mst.model_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        t1.Model_id
      , t1.Model_num
      , COUNT( t1.Catg_code ) as count_cat_num
    FROM model t1
    INNER JOIN car t2 ON t1.model_id = t2.model_id
    WHERE t1.model IN ('CD', 'EM')
    GROUP BY
        t1.Model_id
      , t1.Model_num
    ) model ON prod.Model_id = model.Model_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. But i need catg_code count separtely based on model('CD', 'EM').thats y I wrote separate sql for that (CD and EM). Please check my result in the above

Comment: It will be seperate, due to the group by clause conditions,  that is why I  combined the queries

Comment: I dont want to combine , i need separate column for CD and EM column.Thats i wrote it like that